# Redirect after download xml file

Tags: php, html

I use the following code to download an xml file

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.xml"');
echo simplexml_load_file('temp.xml');
unlink('temp.xml');
?>
```

I would like to redirect to index.php after this. How do I do this?

`header('location...)` and `meta refresh` do not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well because you send the header and content this can't be done.

You have to redirect first and then let the file download on the target site.

Answer (score -1):

Make your website change the url two times with javascript:

```
<script>
  location.href="your_php_file_that_downloads_xml.php";
  location.href="/other/site";
</script>
```